Run a few identical process and then kill one of them
Problem:
Need to run several process, especially it will be “tail -f log.log >> wrile_log.log” proces to collect log.
Commands can be run at the different time for same log file. This is not problem, but..
How do I kill one of them process and not interrupted another?

Remember the PIDs after starting the processes. Often the processes can also be differentiate by the tty or the user on which they were started.
